# Srcollbar doens't change color on the mobile => why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

Here is my app. As you can see scrollbar only horizontal is displayed well, but vertical is as the default. What is strange => on desktop it looks okay, only on the mobile the srcollbar looks in gray color and disapear when it is not in movement. How can I change it?

My code

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--sea-green);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

How can we achieve it?

Comment: Worth reading: [The Current State of Styling Scrollbars in CSS (2022 Update)](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars-in-css/) "Custom scrollbars are extremely rare and that’s mostly due to the fact that scrollbars are one of the remaining bits on the web that are pretty much unstylable..."

Comment: Great idea! Thanks Bro! 

One more question. I see there needs to be set height to make it working

There is set 100 vh, but sometimes when I run the filters to display less elements on the page the scrollbar broke on some position :/ Do you have some ideas for it?